# Path to ISAPI filters with double back slash.

Tags: asp.net, iis, isapi

1. Recently i had an EPIserver site throing an error becaus it could not load the LoadLibraryEx for ISAPI-filter **"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_filter.dll"**. I checked the IIS and the path looked very weird with 2 backslashes. Like this: **"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\\aspnet_filter.dll"** so i changes the path by removing one backslash and checking that the path was correct. Ths site worked.
2. Now i tried to install a new EPiSite and the error came up that it could not load the ISAPI filters but the path was with double backslash!
   3.I read on the internet and found a forum thread about the double backs slash that said that it should be changed in the **C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config**. I checked and the path there was also with doubble slash so i changed it.
3. But now the site gives the same error but with only one back slash. It cant load it.

I dont understand ISAPI filters very well or the IIS, so i wonder if the backslash is something that should be there or if its a mistake, and ofcourse any help to reconfigure it to work is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to check your machine.config also for the filter path.
There might be some problem there.

Comment: Ive search the machine.configs for "Isapi" and "aspnet_filter.dll" but nothing turns up. Where can i find it?